# Unity3d sort of 2D array in Inspector

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have an object which has for example 5 meshes where I would like to change the color in runtime. But every mesh has different colors to change. For example mesh 1 can be changed to blue, red and orange and mesh 2 can be changed to orange, yellow,green,purple and white.

I would like to have a c# script where I have an array with all 5 meshes. And for each array I would like to have another array appear in the inspector, where I can put in the different colors. 
This is no problem if the mesh count would always be 5. But I want it to be flexible. For example, another object only has 3 meshes  than I only need 3 color arrays instead of 5.

I have never worked with Editor Scripts, but maybe there is a easy workaround for that?

I am working with Unity 5.3

Thank you.

Comment: What object type is that "Mesh" you speak of? Do you mean `GameObject`s which are the children of another `GameObject` or are you talking about `UnityEngine.Mesh` objects? Can you give an example object hierarchy? As I understand, you basically want a script that has a `UnityEngine.Color[]` field which has the length of the number of "meshes", then color each mesh according to that color (via a Shader? `material.color`?)

Comment: I mean, I will have a gameobject with several child objects. And I would like to put  some of those child objects into an array, than for each element in that array I will get a new Array with colors. And those colors are coloring that mesh / object trough material.color. So yes, exactly like you said I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Models [] models;
    private int index = 0;
    [SerializeField] private MeshFilter meshFilter = null;
    [SerializeField] private Renderer rend = null;
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if(++index == models.Length)index = 0;
            meshFilter.mesh = models[index].mesh;
            int currIndex = models[index].currentIndex;
            rend.material = models[index].materials[currIndex];
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if(++models[index].currentIndex == models[index].materials.Length)models[index].currentIndex = 0;
            int currIndex = models[index].currentIndex;
            rend.material = models[index].materials[currIndex];
        }
    }   
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Models{
    public Mesh mesh;
    public int currentIndex;
    public Material[]materials;
}
```

This will show the Models array in your inspector. You can give a size for it, then each element opens up a mesh slot and an array of materials. Give it a size and you can start dragging materials.

I would suggest to add 2 items in the array, then add two meshes (Unity has some default ones like sphere and cube). Then create some basic materials of colors and add them to the materials arrays of each object.

Then you can run and press Space to change mesh and A to change color. You just need to use your own after that.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is almost exactly what I need. I just changed it to
 `public Models [] models;
 private int index = 0;
     }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Models{
 public MeshRenderer mesh;
 public Color[] color;
    }`

Comment: If you plan on switching colors, I would recommend switching materials of different colors. I read somewhere unity creates a new material when accessing color. Kinda weird I agree.

Comment: Hm I read "you will only get a new material instance once...the first time you change any material property", so I guess not a problem for me. But thanks for the advice.